# Awk average of column by moving difference of grouping column variable

Tags: linux, unix, awk

I have a file that look like this:

```
1 snp1 0.0 4
1 snp2 0.2 6
1 snp3 0.3 4
1 snp4 0.4 3
1 snp5 0.5 5
1 snp6 0.6 6
1 snp7 1.3 5
1 snp8 1.3 3
1 snp9 1.9 4
```

File is sorted by column 3. I want the average of 4th column grouped by column 3 every 0.5 unit apart. For example it should output like this:

```
1 snp1 0.0 4.4
1 snp6 0.6 6.0
1 snp7 1.3 4.0
1 snp9 1.9 4.0
```

I can print all positions without average like this:

```
awk 'NR==1 {pos=$3; print $0} $3>=pos+0.5{pos=$3; print $0}' input
```

But I am not able to figure out how to print average of 4th column. It would be great if someone can help me to find solution to this problem. Thanks!

Comment: You should explain if the file is sorted and, if yes, according what criteria.

Comment: File is sorted by column 3. I have added that to the query. Thanks.

Comment: Much better. Could you also explain what value you want for column 2 in your output?

Comment: Column 2 should have value corresponding to first instance or occurrence  of value in column 3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this, maybe:

```
awk '
  NR==1 {c1=$1; c2=$2; v=$3; n=1; s=$4; next}
  $3>v+0.5 {print c1, c2, v, s/n; c1=$1; c2=$2; v=$3; n=1; s=$4; next}
  {n+=1; s+=$4}
  END {print c1, c2, v, s/n}
' input
```